# non standard extension warning when searching in a vector of unique_ptrs

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, compiler-warnings, unique-ptr

In the following code snippet:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec;
vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(1));
vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(2));
vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(3));
vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(4));
vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(5));
auto & itr = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](std::unique_ptr<int> & val)->bool
{
   return *val == 5;
});
vec.erase(itr);
```

I get the following warning:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning C4239   nonstandard extension used: 'initializing': conversion from 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>>' to 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>> &'
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am on VS2015 and this warning comes up only at warning level 4. Should I just ignore it or could it result in any sneaky problems(if similar code involving vector of `unique_ptr`s was used in a larger context)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns the iterator to the matching element by value, and you're trying to bind that to a non-const reference, which is illegal. The VC++ compiler has an infamous extension that allows this, but thankfully generates a warning when you set `/W4`. Change your code to

```
auto itr = std::find_if(...);
```

Comment: This is a spurious warning.I got it when assigning a lambda to an lvalue ref type variable. Do you think we should treat it as an error and be cross platform and standard compliant?

Comment: @Nik-Lz If you mean code like `auto& l = []{};`, that's not a spurious warning, that code is illegal. You should either turn C4239 into an error or compile with `/permissive-` which will reject the code.

Answer (score 4):

You take temporary by non-const reference on return from find_if.

Either do

```
auto itr = ... ;
```

or

```
const auto& itr =  ... ;
```

Comment: or `auto&& itr = ... ;`, if we're playing the bind-to-reference game.